# human_attribute_name defaults to the wrong locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, internationalization, yaml, rails-i18n

I am developing a localised application with Rails 3.2.8, deployed on Heroku.
I created a localisation it.yml file with the following structure:

```
it:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      company:
        name:             "Nome"
        address:          "Indirizzo"
        phone:            "Telefono"
```

I then use:

```
Company.human_attribute_name(:name)
```

to get localised labels in my views.
The default locale is :it.

When I switch to English everything works fine on my local environment, but once I deploy to Heroku something goes wrong with the localisation, and human_attribute_name seems to return Italian even when I switch the locale.

Am I doing something wrong with the above, or missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause. In my production environment I had:

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

Switching it to *false* made the application behave correctly.